# Jmeter - How to loop until certain integer - 'While contoller' nested in the 'Loop contoller'

Tags: jmeter

My Architecture is like this:

[image]

From JsonPath I extract all the programID's like:

[image]

When Executed is like this:

[image]

*The question is: How to tell the while controller is loop until programId 80?*

What I tried is:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think correct [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) would be something like:

```
${__groovy((vars.get('programId_' + vars.get('Counter')) as int) > 80,)}
```

in general I wouldn't recommend inlining [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Groovy scripts as it's bad for performance and may cause issues, go for code-based equivalents instead, in the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

A better option would be amending your JSONPath query to return IDs which are above 80, see [Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)

Comment: This is what I get if I put suggested _groovy() function  -> 2022-10-03 16:44:18,372 WARN o.a.j.f.Groovy: Error running groovy script
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead

Comment: It means that either `Counter` variable doesn't exist or `programId_X` doesn't exist or both, use [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter) to see what variables are present and what are their values.

Comment: please note I dont have var Counter, probably that's why I got this error.

Comment: If you don't have var Counter why you're trying to use it?

Comment: because I need to increment the programID

Comment: I also tried as: ${__groovy((vars.get('programId_' + ${__counter(,)}) as int) > 80,)}     -> but still not working

Comment: I cannot help to people who not paying any attention to what I'm saying (about inlining JMeter Functions and Variables into Groovy scripts) and neither know [how to properly ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologize, I miss that part. Let me try to limit within the JSON path, as your advice is suitable. Will pay more attention in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dmitri T for your direction.
The honey for me in this case was the alteration the JSON path expression to:

```
$..pageItems[?(@.programId>80)].programId
```

Like this I was able to filter all the programId higher than 80.